# Best way to start GitFlow for a current project

Tags: git, git-flow

I am very new to Git and I think the GitFlow workflow is the one I want to follow.
I have a project which is in its second version right now. I want to store the first version (which i still have a copy of) as V1 and then store my second version which is near completion as V2
How do I go about this.
Are there any video tutorials for GitFlow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "keep" history between the previously not in CM software, I'd do the following.

Copy the V1 software (assuming you have all of the source) into a directory and do the following.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Saving V1"
git tag V1
git checkout -b dev
```

Then I'd copy the files from V2 over into the same directory and do the following.

```
git add .
git commit -m "current work towards V2"
```

From here on out, to follow [git-flow], you're going to want to create feature branches off of `dev` for each feature/bug, then merge them into dev when finished. Then when v2 is ready, merge it into `master`. I usually add a tag to signify a named version of the software.

There is a lot more that you're going to want to do/learn (.gitignore, `git rebase`, remote repos, etc...) but the above should be 'good' enough to get you started.

---

EDIT:

A little rundown of what [each step](http://git-scm.com/docs) is doing:

`git init` creates a git repository in the current directory

`git add .` adds all files into the staging area

`git commit -m "text"` creates a commit with a message

`git tag name` adds a tag to the current commit so that you can reference by this name

`git checkout -n newBranchName` creates a new branch from the current HEAD location and then does a `checkout`